# logging errors based on parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-handling

Is their a way to log an error that occurred due to a parameter being passed in? 
i.e

```
PROCEDURE customer_collateral_hist(i_Vcust_cd   IN customer_collateral_history.cust_cd%TYPE,
                                   i_Vfromdate  IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vtodate    IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vauthstat  IN customer_collateral_history.auth_stat%TYPE,
                                   o_Cresultset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   AS
   BEGIN
      OPEN o_Cresultset FOR
         SELECT auth_stat,
            buld_size,
            clos_dt,
            cnfm_dt,
            cnfm_tm,
            cnfm_user_id,
            cust_cd,
            date_seq,
            dbtr,
            dbtr_addr,
            dbtr_id,
            dbtr_tel_no,
            dbtr_zip_cd1,
            dbtr_zip_cd2,
            esta_orga,
            grnt_dt_from,
            grnt_dt_to,
            jdg_amt,
            jdg_dt,
            land_size,
            loc_addr,
            mort_amt,
            mort_chng_dt,
            mort_flag,
            mort_max_amt,
            mort_seq,
            mort_stat,
            old_key,
            ownr,
            ownr_addr,
            ownr_id,
            ownr_tel_no,
            ownr_zip_cd1,
            ownr_zip_cd2,
            prev_mort_amt,
            redm_dt,
            reg_dt,
            reg_dttm,
            reg_flag,
            reg_user_id,
            remark,
            supr_pow_flag
       FROM customer_collateral_history
         WHERE cust_cd LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vcust_cd, cust_cd)||'%'
        AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) >= NVL(i_Vfromdate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) <= NVL(i_Vtodate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND auth_stat LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vauthstat, auth_stat)||'%';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       NULL;
   END customer_collateral_hist;

END customer;
/
```

In this above procedure I am going to change the exception handler by calling this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure 
        APMS.write_error_log ( errstr varchar2, errline varchar2) 
    IS
        pragma autonomous_transaction; 
        -- this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
    begin                         
              INSERT INTO error_log
                  (err_tmsp,
                   err_msg,
                err_line_no
                )
          values (systimestamp,
                  errstr,
                  errline
                  );
          COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
    end write_error_log;
```

For example, My write_error_log procedure, so far, logs the time, message and line number of the error encountered in a procedure to an error_log table. However, the last step would be writing in some code that would allow the write_error_log procedure to capture an error that involves data being called in the parameter. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please do not use WHEN OTHERS THEN null;  It hides the error and the point of the questions you are asking is logging the errors

Comment: I understand that, my write_error_log is going to be called in that exception handler so it catches the errors. 'When others then null' is merely a place holder.

Comment: What sort of error are you thinking that you might get opening a cursor?  Unless you have a blatant data type issue (in which case you should fix the query), opening a cursor isn't going to throw an error.  It's much more likely that you'd get an error when fetching from the cursor or that you would want to implement some business logic that treats, say, a cursor returning 0 rows as an error.

Comment: I suppose your second point. In the case that i'd get an error when fetching a cursor or data from an "IN' parameter.

Comment: But if your procedure is merely opening the cursor and some other piece of code is fetching the data, your exception handler couldn't be in this procedure.  It would need to be in the calling procedure which would have to know what parameters were originally passed in.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to check your parameters when they arrive through the use of an ASSERT statement.  [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o33plsql-l1-101540.html) shows the ASSERT function.  Statements like this are listed as one technique that is used by NASA for [safety critical code](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Power_of_10:_Rules_for_Developing_Safety-Critical_Code).

Just add a series of asserts at the start of every function or procedure that indicates what you expect the range of values to be.  If they are within the range an exception is thrown that you can catch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to dynamically at runtime examine the parameter values in the call stack. You might want to look at adding either one or both of the following into your exception log

dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace
dbms_utility.format_error_stack

And adding another parameter to it as well to allow the calling program to send a message - and have every exception block pass to your procedure a list of the input parameters and their values.

So

```
PROCEDURE customer_collateral_hist(i_Vcust_cd   IN customer_collateral_history.cust_cd%TYPE,
                                   i_Vfromdate  IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vtodate    IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vauthstat  IN customer_collateral_history.auth_stat%TYPE,
                                   o_Cresultset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   AS
   BEGIN
      OPEN o_Cresultset FOR
         SELECT auth_stat,
            buld_size,
            clos_dt,
            cnfm_dt,
            cnfm_tm,
            cnfm_user_id,
            cust_cd,
            date_seq,
            dbtr,
            dbtr_addr,
            dbtr_id,
            dbtr_tel_no,
            dbtr_zip_cd1,
            dbtr_zip_cd2,
            esta_orga,
            grnt_dt_from,
            grnt_dt_to,
            jdg_amt,
            jdg_dt,
            land_size,
            loc_addr,
            mort_amt,
            mort_chng_dt,
            mort_flag,
            mort_max_amt,
            mort_seq,
            mort_stat,
            old_key,
            ownr,
            ownr_addr,
            ownr_id,
            ownr_tel_no,
            ownr_zip_cd1,
            ownr_zip_cd2,
            prev_mort_amt,
            redm_dt,
            reg_dt,
            reg_dttm,
            reg_flag,
            reg_user_id,
            remark,
            supr_pow_flag
       FROM customer_collateral_history
         WHERE cust_cd LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vcust_cd, cust_cd)||'%'
        AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) >= NVL(i_Vfromdate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) <= NVL(i_Vtodate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND auth_stat LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vauthstat, auth_stat)||'%';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       write_error_log(SQLERRM, 'Params i_vcust_cd: '||e_vcustid||' eVfromdate: '||t_vFromDate....);
       -- if you want to halt execution then re-raise the error up the stack
       RAISE;
   END customer_collateral_hist;
```

And then add to your handler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure 
        APMS.write_error_log ( errstr varchar2, p_tracetext varchar2) 
    IS
        pragma autonomous_transaction; 
        -- this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
    begin                         
              INSERT INTO error_log
                  (err_tmsp,
                   err_msg,
                   trace_Text
                )
          values (systimestamp,
                  errstr,
                  'BackTrace: '||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace
                  ||chr(10)||' Stack: '||dbms_utility.format_error_stack
                  ||' details: '||p_tracetext 
                  );
          COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
    end write_error_log;
```

Things you will have to manage is ensuring consistent coding practices to give you the deatils you need, and if you are raising the exception out to the calling program you would have this repeated each step of the way out the call stack - which is not terribly efficient. To avoid that you need to log the stack and details at the lowest depth of the stack, and write once at the top of the stack on your way out. Not hard to do - but again requires diligent coding practices.

Good luck with it!